# Why can you use new Image but not new Div or new Span?

Tags: javascript, html, w3c

In examples I've seen `new Image()` to create a new HTML image element but when I try `new Div()` there is no support. Is there a reason for this or any plan in the future to add it?

Example:

```
var image = new Image();
var div = new Div(); // error
```

Comment: This is just a guess. Images are complete in and of themselves. There is no such thing as `<img>Suff</img>`. `<div>` on the other hand is almost always a container for something else.

Comment: @James A Mohler: Why would it make sense for a void element to have a unique constructor and simultaneously not make sense for a non-void element to have one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Div` class doesn't exist. Any DOM Element can be created using the function [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var img = document.createElement('img');
```

`document.createElement('div')` creates a new [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement).

[`new Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) creates in fact an [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) and is equivalent to `document.createElement('img')`.

Images can be created using the [`new Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) syntax for historical reasons. Back in the 90s, the `Image` object has been one of the first dynamic HTML feature implemented by all browsers before the current [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) was even invented (not to mention implemented the same way by all browsers).

Comment: 5 answers, and yours is the _only one_ actually answering the question... thanks for that. Anyway I guess one should expect historical reasons to show their ugly heads whenever something weird happens on Web APIs =p - Also it'd be cool if you had an external source supporting your claim.

Comment: @Paul Stenne: And they say "Stack Overflow prides itself on high-quality Q&A with answers from experts..." at least, these *do* come along every now and then :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question why that method exists. The HTML Living Standard doesn't answer that question (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-image). It just states there is a constructor for HTMLImageElements provided in addition to the factory method
`document.createElement('img')`

With this function you can create all DOM elements, e.g.
`document.createElement('div')`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Whether these constructors will be implemented for other elements I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

My Google search concluded that you are using Web Api

It may also be due to existence of constructor:

1. HTMLImageElement has constructor as Image(), so it allows new Image()
2. HTMLDivElement has no constructor

source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement